# App slow on Server 2008 r2 but fast on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, performance

I have an app that runs fast on windows 7, but when I host it on windows server 2008 r2, it's much slower. I've turned power power options to 'Hi Performance' and set optimization to programs rather than background tasks. It helps but the app is still much slower.

Here are some details on the app: It's an app that converts a 5250 data stream from an IBM midrange from green screen to a graphical app. Conversion runs locally on the client using an active x control. When I run the green screen directly, it's fast. When I add in graphic conversion, it's slow. Hardware is a 3.4g 8 core with 8g ram.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: You're testing the exact same app on the same hardware, just on the two different OSes?

Comment: Correct. Same hardware. Different OS.

Comment: Is the Windows 7 install x86 or x64? Is the hardware a desktop, or server?

Comment: 64 bit on a desktop.

Comment: Aha - does Windows 2008 R2 have the same video and chipset drivers for your hardware?

Comment: No. We're also running Citrix on top of it and we have to use the citrix video driver, which is not the same as the windows 7 driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we've identified your problem. The hardware in question is a desktop, and Windows Server (running Citrix) doesn't have the correct video driver. This sounds like a graphics-intensive operation. That will be a performance problem, yes.

You may be out of luck. Get hardware and drivers that is supported on the OS you intend to deploy the solution on. Alternatively, the application vendor may have some tweaks to recommend. Used to be a time when CAD vendors released their own video card drivers (maybe some still do.)